# UI Automation and internationalization

Tags: c#, internationalization, automation

I'm developing an UI automation client for a MS Office.

One anticipated issue is how this tool might interact with  MS office running with different language packs, e.g. French or Chinese. Since we use text string corresponding to UI element names for searching and querying, it seems this will break under a different language pack.

We haven't tried anything with multiple language packs but I wonder if anyone's had any experience with this that could provide pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally bad practice to develop automation that is reliant on using text for Object identification. As you are discovering, you are limited to running on English.

I would recommend that you develop your automation to be locale independent - this can be achieved by using a unique identifier rather than the text e.g. the objects class, id etc.

I blogged about this a while ago - see [here](http://www.jimmycollins.org/blog/?p=28)